# Revert QGIS2.6 installation to QGIS 2.4 through OSGeo4W Advanced installer

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

It is possible to return to QGIS 2.4 OSGeo4W installation when I have QGIS 2.6?

I want to do this with advanced installer.

Comment: You can have multiple QGIS versions installed (I have both 2.2 and 2.6). If you want to only keep 2.4, you will have to completely remove 2.6. If you have both, project files will automatically load in the latest QGIS version you have.

Comment: There is no conflict with having several versions?

Comment: As @AndreJ mentioned, the main conflicts will come with the different plugin versions. I haven't experienced any other conflicts (that's not to say it never happens!).

Comment: No conflict if you use different folders, like OSGEO4W22, OSGEO4W24 and OSGEO4W26.

Comment: @Joseph you can click on `../apps/qgis/bin/qgis.reg` of the desired version to change the default startup when doubleclicking a project file.

Comment: @AndreJ ahh very good to know. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

You can revert to QGIS 2.4 only if you have the QGIS 2.4 installation files still on disk. You can click on the version number in advanced install to toggle between the available versions. On the server you will find only 2.6.1.1 and 2.6.0.1.

A better way is to use the standalone installer, which can be found at this site:

http://qgis.org/downloads/

for all past versions.

The main obstacle is that you can not switch the plugins between older versions.
You van find older plugin versions at http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/, but they will be stored on your computer in the same place.

Especially the current Openlayers plugin will not work with older QGIS versions.